# NServiceBus message handling Create/Update

Tags: nservicebus

We have a message, "Person". All works fine with UPDATE with a **PersonHandler**. However now we need to add a new **Person**. (Previously, add new Person was done through a CRM system so we don't have to worry about insertion). Now we need to move that functionality to our new NSB system. Once a **Person** is added I need to pass the GUID of that Person to the front end. To do this should I use request/response model with NSB or use plain ADO.Net code? If I used the later, we will have our insertion code at the client side with ADO.Net and Updates in NSB. Which doesn't looks right to me.

This may be a foolish question, but I really appreciate if you guys can point me to the right direction on the architectural point of view.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to new up the Person GUID on the client and then pass that in the message to the server - you wouldn't need a response back from the server. That would probably be simplest.

You could also do request/response as shown in the Full Duplex and AsyncPages samples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Really appreciate it. Issue is AddNew has to be done through CRM classes, there are heaps of business logic built in to them and replicate that logic is a different project by itself.
If I am going to have a code just to add a "Empty Person" from the client side, i have to add references to old CRM dlls at the client as well, which looks ugly. 
May be I am looking into this NSB in a wrong angle :(

Comment: Well, I didn't like to move into request/response. So the options were to make the Insertion logic a non NSB procedure call or to change the UI (once a Person is added, user is redirected to a confirmation page, because otherwise if he refresh on the page, back end will add another Person as front end is not aware of the previous insertion). We end up in changing the UI. Thanks for your help Udi. Cheers!